# How do the "Blink and You'll Miss It: 1 Turn Victory" Duel Replays manage to win?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-duel-links

I decided to check out the Duel Replays at the PVP Arena. I tried watching the ones under "Blink and You'll Miss It: 1 Turn Victory", and true to it's name, I barely blink before the game is over. Both players draw cards, then they somehow win. Here is a log of the duel:

[image: Blink and You'll Miss It: 1 Turn Victory duel log]

I watched a few others and they all turn out the same way: both players draw their hands, then one of them inexplicably wins without playing a single card.

I don't understand what is going on here. There isn't a reason for the victory, like life points going to zero. And Exodia isn't in the game yet, so it's not like they drew all the pieces in the starting hand. They just go from drawing cards to victory. What happened? How did they win?

Comment: I have no experience in this game, so this is wild speculation... Is it possible that one player surrendered and the log simply doesn't show that?

Comment: @MageXy Usually when a player surrenders, it will say "You Win" followed by "Opponent Surrendered" (or "You Lose" and "You surrendered"). I don't see that in the logs or the screen that displays during the match. Although I suppose it's still possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update***

I finally had this annoying bug happen to me, and there is one small thing that the duel logs does *not* show - a *Waiting for Response* message. After this message disappears, it will either continue the duel as normal or I will receive the *failed*  message.

[image]

---

I have watched quite a few of the “Blink and You'll Miss It: 1 Turn Victory” replays and I will have to say this is an interesting occurrence.

The opponent did not [Surrender](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Surrender), as the duel log will display "*You/Your Opponent Surrendered*" instead of "*Failed*"

[image]

These "victories" also do not fit into a [Zero Turn Kills](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Zero_Turn_Kill), [First Turn Kills](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/First_Turn_Kill), or [One Turn Kills](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/One_Turn_Kill), leaving the only other explanation is being a **poorly implemented network disconnection bug**.

As discussed on this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DuelLinks/comments/5osqke/opponent_wins_failed_when_duel_links_wants_to/) post, it talks about how this is a bug in the PvP arena. This duel made it all the way to Turn 12 before disconnecting with both players still having Life Points remaining.

[image]

In addition to the reddit post, I watched a replay where the opponents Life Points went from 4,000 to 0 to 4,000 in a faction of a second; literally within a blink. The image below shows a "victory" even while the opponent still have 4,000 Life Points.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Someone lost connection to the game or surrendered

Comment: Welcome to Gaming Stack Exchange! I usually see different messages when an opponent surrenders. While a game disconnection is plausible, what leads you to think that the message "Failure" means disconnection?